# Why am I getting errors?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cs50

I'm trying to create a program that accepts cmd line arguments to encipher a plaintext!
The program must accept one cmd line argument after its name when making it and this would be the key which by the plaintext (only) alphabetical characters are rotated by this key (e.g. it's number is added to the real alphabet ASCII number resulting in another alphabet to be printed!

it is supposed to print an error message when one argument is present (e.g. here:/make encipher)
instead of here:/make encipher 12 <-- 12 = key!

**I am getting a segmentation fault when running the program without the key argument, why?**

This is the full code. I'm posting it because I need to learn where is my fault's exact location
and why is it triggered?!

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //  To use atoi (converting a string to an int)
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

bool key_is_numb(string argv[]);
void encipher(string txt, int key);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (key_is_numb(argv) == false)
        {
            printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
            return 1;
        }

    else
    {
    int key = atoi(argv[1]);
    string plaintext;

            if (argc == 2 && key > 0)
                {
                    plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
                    encipher(plaintext, key);  //  A function that prints the ciphered text
                    return 0;   //  returns Zero as main return value which means "All good"!
                }

            else if (argc == 1 || argc > 2 || key <= 0)
                {
                    printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
                    return 1;
                }

    }   //  End else.

}   // End main()å func.



bool key_is_numb(string argv[])
{
    int n = strlen(argv[1]);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //  checking element by element in the second string of the argv[] array of strings
    {
        if (isdigit(argv[1][i]) == 0)   //  if the entered string "key" contains chars other than digits.
        {
            return false;   //  break out of the if statement & the entire function key_is_numb()
                            //  and return false as soon as a letter is encountered.
        }

        else
        {
            continue;   //  go up & start the next iteration for the for loop.
        }
    //  if only digits encountered then this for loop will come to an end and exist from here.
    }   //  End for loop

    return true;   //  function exits and return boolean true from here.

}   // End key_is_numb() func.


void encipher(string txt, int key)
{
    printf("ciphertext: ");
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(txt); i <= n; i++)    // strlen counts the number of elements in a string excluding '\0'
    {
        char c = txt[i];

        if (isalpha(c))
        {
            if (isupper(c))
            {
                char m = 'A';   //  This is a modifyer character equals to 'A' = 65 so that it is indexed @ ZERO!
                printf("%c", (c - m + key) % 26 + m );
                //c = ((((int)txt[i] - 65) + key) % 26) + 65; //  char c = 65 <-- 65 is an ASCII code equals 'A'
            }
            else if (islower(c))
            {
                char m = 'a';   //  This is a modifying character 'a' = 97
                printf("%c", (c - m + key) % 26 + m );
            }
        }//  End if(alpha).

        else
        {
            printf("%c", c);
        }

    }   //  End for().
        printf("\n");

}   //  End encipher() func.
```

Comment: Your code _asumes_ there is always an `argv[1]`. You should check `argc` which tells the number of arguments.

Comment: *I'm posting it because I need to learn where is my fault's exact location and why is it triggered?!* -- That is the purpose of a debugger, and why it is an important tool to learn how to use.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Please post your answers in the answer section. Thank you.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings My comment really wasn't an answer.  Maybe you directed to the wrong commenter?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I guess you meant Paul O., not Paul M. ;-)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, I did :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Segmentation fault in program using command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691457/segmentation-fault-in-program-using-command-line-arguments)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19641597/what-is-segmentation-fault-core-dumped

Comment: Is `string` a type alias for `char*`? If so, _why_ do something that confusing?

Comment: @TedLyngmo `string` is a `cs50.h` typedef alias for `char *`. It belongs to `cs50.h`

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Thanks! It's not as bad as it was when the question still had the C++ tag - but still ... that's a nasty alias. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you are assuming that argv[1] is defined in `key_is_numb`. However, in C and C++, the second parameter of the main function contains command line arguments. Which, in your case will be the name of the binary as the first element, then any other arguments. This is why when you are running the program without arguments, it will segfault, as there are no argument to put in argv, and no default value either.

You should always check the size of `argv`, by using the number stored in `argc`, before trying to read anything in `argv`.

Your segmentation fault comes from this line `int n = strlen(argv[1]);`, but I'd highly suggest you to learn to use debugger software like valgrind, which if the program has been compiled with debug flag will tell you the exact line.

Other debugger are really useful too, so you should learn to use them, as they usually report this kind of errors.

Answer (score 3):

```
int n = strlen(argv[1]);
```

in `key_is_numb()` and

```
int key = atoi(argv[1]);
```

in `main()`.

If you didn't enter a key argument, `argv[1]` as equal as `argv[argc]` is a null pointer as stated in C17, §5.1.2.2.1/2.

Any attempt to access its data is [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984) and probably caused the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2):

Your code asumes there is always an `argv[1]`. You should check `argc` which tells the number of arguments. For example:

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Key required\n");
        exit (1);
    }
```